# Automatically clear users cache on app update in android

Tags: android

Is there any method in the android API (ideally for 2.3.6 and onwards) that clears the users cache if they download a new version of an app? Looking around there doesn't seem to be any mention of one - or am I off the ball completely and the cache is emptied when a new version is installed?

Comment: If nothing else, store a file with your `android:versionCode` in the cache, and check it on startup, wiping out your own cache if needed.

Comment: Hey neilK, if your problem is fixed you can ask @CommonsWare to post it as an answer, or add it yourself as an answer and accept your own answer. There's no need to add "solved" on this site, the 'accept' button is for that :)

Comment: @Nanne ,I  wasn't sure how to accept a comment as an answer, now I know the protocol - thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If nothing else, store a file with your `android:versionCode` in the cache, and check it on startup, wiping out your own cache if needed - `@CommonsWare`

Answer (score 4):

Use the BroadcastReceiver  to receive update notification of your application with intent filter android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED .
In your onReceive method of update receiver verify intent action as Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED . And then do whatever you need to do your old cache.

Comment: This sounds like the correct way to do it. The accepted answer would put running code in every onStart() call I assume. However, will the receiver get a broadcast if it the app was disabled?